# Defining common variables for multiple Fitnesse test cases and suites

Tags: fitnesse

I am trying to create test suites in Fitnesse. One test case can be in multiple suites. For every test suite, I have different parameters to pass. Is there any way I can define common paramaters at some place and use them in many test cases and suites instead of duplicating the Fitnesse pages? In our  development environment, we have to run the application with different configurations and parameters for testing. It will be very difficult to maintain when the application grows large.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done. Put all the test cases that share common variable in same suite and define variable as suite level or `SetUp` page (which will be automatically included in all the test pages).

If for some reason you cannot do above then put all the `!define` on a page and include that page using include directive `!include` on all the pages you want those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple Suites with different configurations by defining common variables here. Then setup Symbolic Links to those test suites (you have already created) in the "properties" page.

you can refer to this page
http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.SymbolicLinks

The idea is similar to managing testing in different environments.